# Putting plywood between layers of attic insulation

Tags: insulation

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I've searched an haven't been able to come up with anything helpful.

I'm planning on wiring my house for Ethernet, and I'm going up to the attic to do some cable drops.  My attic has blown fibreglass insulation which rises well above the top of the joists.  All the advice I've read says I should carefully rake the insulation away from where I plan to walk, and lay down some plywood planks to make sure I don't accidentally step through the ceiling, and to rake the insulation back when I'm done.  That's all well and good, but, I expect I'm going to complete this project over a couple of weekends, which makes me wonder, if I leave the plywood in place and rake the insulation back on top of it, effectively giving me a layer of insulation above and below my walkway, will the effectiveness of the insulation decrease?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Not enough to be noticeable. Don't compact it when replacing it.

Answer (score 5):

Yep, that's fine. It won't degrade the insulation's performance at all. You can even make a permanent walkway consisting of plywood on top of rigid foam insulation where it would penetrate the layer of blown fiberglass.

Comment: I second the answer. People do that all the time in there attics. Just as long as you do not really compact the insulation underneath the plywood it will not reduce its effectiveness.